# Class Rewritting. Not working core function works by default

Tags: magento-1.9, module, overrides

I am creating a new model. insted to core module modification. as
[image: Catagory]

**Catagory.php** But it runs core by default

```
   <?php

   class TutsPlus_Catalog_Model_Category extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Category 
  {

 public function getChildren()
      {
      die("this");
      return $this->getResource()->getChildren($this, false);
      }
   }
```

**My etc->config.xml**

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0"?> <config>   <modules>
>     <TutsPlus_Catalog>
>         <version>0.1.1</version>
>     </TutsPlus_Catalog>
> </modules>   <global>
>  <models>
>    <tutplus>
>         <class>TutsPlus_Catalog_Model</class>
>   </tutplus>
>    <catalog>
>       <rewrite><category>TutsPlus_Catalog_Model_Category</category></rewrite>
>    </catalog>
>  </models>   </global> </config>
> ```

AND The modules->TutsPlus_Catalog.xml

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0"?>  <config>
>   <modules>
>       <TutsPlus_Catalog>
>           <active>true</active>
>           <codePool>local</codePool>
>       </TutsPlus_Catalog>
>   </modules> </config>
> ```

**My tesp.php**

```
     require_once 'app/Mage.php';
     Mage::app();

    $category = Mage::getModel("Catalog/Category")->load(3);
    var_dump($category->getChildren());
```

The problem is it executes the core modules itself. not the new one

**Output loaded from core module**
[image]

Comment: you sure you have correct xml ?

Comment: check error log

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gX287MS3 check this one updated xml

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pDrjMmY2

Comment: check second xml.`<?xml version="1.0"?>` tag is missing

Comment: don't forget to clean the cache after changes in the config

Comment: Updated the Question still not working and cleared the cache system->cacheManagement->configuration    log file is empty

Comment: is your module showing up as being loaded? You can see this in the Magento admin section under `System->Config->Advanced->Disable Modules Output`?

Comment: i don't see any issue in code now

Comment: @David Manners The module is visible in admin panel but if you notice that i used die("this");   then the output must be **this**  in display but it takes from core class.

Comment: https://github.com/vishalpardeshi/magento_E-com_Application/blob/master/app/code/local/TutsPlus/Catalog/etc/config.xml   can check my config.xml

Comment: Finally got solution for this Issue by combination's. the change to lower case and manual congif clear from here. :(

  Most Important. and output worked. no more reputation cant upvote. Thanks for all for your help New to megento Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind this error is the usage of uppercase when getting the model.

```
$category = Mage::getModel("Catalog/Category")->load(3);
```

If instead you use `catalog/category` then it will load the correct model.

The reason this does not throw an error but instead loads the Magento class is because of a line in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php` which will try to load a Mage class by default if a class name is not matched.:

```
if (empty($className)) {
    $className = 'mage_'.$group.'_'.$groupType;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `etc/config.xml` is incomplete. It **must** contain the `modules` element, matching the module name from `app/etc/modules/TutsPlus_Catalog.xml`:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <TutsPlus_Catalog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </TutsPlus_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: **Should i do like this** 
      <config>  <modules>
        <TutsPlus_Catalog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </TutsPlus_Catalog>
    </modules>

  <global>
     <models>
       <catalog>
          <rewrite>
            <category>TutsPlus_Catalog_Model_Category</category>
          </rewrite>
       </catalog>
     </models>
  </global>
</config>

Comment: @vishalpardeshi yes - why don't you try it?

Comment: No still not working

Comment: Please check i have modified my Question..

Comment: don't forget to clean the cache after changes in the config

Comment: have done but still not working

Answer (score 0):

if you want a full detailed tutorial about class rewriting I suggest you looking at this blog post I have written recently

https://www.sherodesigns.com/how-to-override-rewrite-classes-in-magento/

Thanks.

Comment: where i can get more detail tutorial about magento video / blog

Comment: did you understand it from the link I shared?

Comment: yes i have solved the issue but i need all magento tutorial's to clear logic for basic's  oop' s concept  the **tutorial** was excellent. Thank you